# matrix representation of free group with metric requirement

Tags: representation-theory

Look at this Cayley diagram of the free group generated by 2 elements, $F_2 = \langle a, b \rangle$:

[image]

The 2 elements marked by green and pink are "unrelated" in the sense that they are far apart in the Cayley diagram.  In other words, 2 nodes are "closer" to each other if they share the longer prefix.  For example, "aaaaa" is closer to "aaaab" than to "ab".

So I require a property: 
**Prefix proximity**:  The distance metric D has to be such that $D(x,y) < D(x,z)$ whenever x,y shares a longer prefix than x,z, $\forall x \neq y \neq z \in F$.

( It seems that this is equivalent to: $D(x,xy) \le D(x,y) \;,\; \forall x,y \in F$ but I have not verified. )

My question is whether any matrix representation (ie, any subgroup of GL(n)) meeting this criterion can exist.  The distance between 2 matrices could be measured by the Frobenius norm, ie, flatten the matrix into a vector and then $\sqrt{\sum v^2_i}$.

Background:  this is for a computer science application where I want to represent sentences such as "john $\cdot$ loves $\cdot$ mary" and "yesterday $\cdot$ was $\cdot$ raining".  If the matrix representations of the above 2 sentences can get arbitrarily close in vector space, it would be rather useless for numerical algorithms;  hence my requirement.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you really talking about a free group as opposed to a free monoid? Do you use inverses anywhere in your application?

Comment: (In the presence of inverses it's less clear what you mean by sharing a longer prefix, since it might be possible to change the length of the shared prefix by inserting $a a^{-1}$ or something somewhere, e.g. consider $abab$ vs. $abb$ vs. $ab a a^{-1} b$.)

Comment: Yes you're right, I need the free monoid only.  Does it change the nature of the question drastically?

Comment: It might make it easier (and it removes any ambiguity about what you might mean by the common prefix of two elements). I don't know because I still don't have much of a grasp on the metric condition you're requiring.

Comment: Intuitively, if 2 nodes are far apart on the above diagram, then they are far apart.  In other words, the above embedding is an example that satisfies the condition...  but I guess we need to spell out the condition explicitly.

Comment: PS:  I think I have seen such a distance defined in the book "Large Scale Geometry" by Nowak and Yu 2012, but I don't have the book here now.  It's called the "length" between x,y.

Comment: Is it important for your application that the map from the free monoid to matrices be a homomorphism? Based on what you've said it sounds more like you might just want an efficiently computable isometric (or something) embedding from the free monoid (with essentially the word metric: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) into some Euclidean space, or something. Does that sound right?

Comment: If so, I believe that such an embedding can't exist. The problem is that balls in the word metric get exponentially large with the radius (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_%28group_theory%29), but balls in Euclidean space can only intersect polynomially many elements of a discrete subset as a function of the radius. So you can't guarantee a condition like two distinct words being at least $\varepsilon > 0$ apart for any fixed $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yes the word metric is exactly what I need.  If we take square matrices to be the nodes, with Frobenius distance, then we can have an embedding but not homomorphism with respect to matrix multiplication.  But it may still work for my purposes.  Thanks for helping :)

By the way, I don't follow your reasoning above.  It seems that it would fail only if we require matrix multiplication to hold...

Comment: The argument above makes no use of matrix multiplication. It shows that you can't avoid the possibility of distinct words being arbitrarily close in an embedding into a Euclidean space, which from the background it sounds like you were trying to avoid.

Comment: To clarify, let me call my required condition "prefix relatedness", ie, elements that share longer prefixes are closer to each other.  Notice that the Cayley graph when embedded on the Euclidean plane satisfies this property, which means that prefix-relatedness does not imply hyperbolicity.  Gromov's idea seems to be that if we require the distance between nodes to be equal to the word metric, then the embedding must occur in hyperbolic space.

Comment: If we think of the above Cayley graph as having matrix nodes, with the Frobenius norm (ie, the matrices are just vectors in $R^{n^2}$), then the matrices exist in Euclidean space, satisfying my condition, but it is not an embedding in Gromov's sense.  So the question is still open as to whether matrix representations satisfying my condition can exist...

Comment: Then I don't understand the relationship between your condition and the comment you made in the background. In the background you say "If the matrix representations of the above 2 sentences can get arbitrarily close in vector space, it would be rather useless for numerical algorithms," so it seems like you're worried about unrelated words being too close together. But based on your comment it sounds like you're worried about related words being too far apart. Which is it?

Comment: PS: $R^{n^2}$ cannot be $R^2$ as that would imply $n=\sqrt{2}$, not an integer.  But I guess the same reasoning works for $R^4$, say.

Comment: I also don't believe that the Cayley graph as drawn above satisfies your condition. $a$ and $ab$ look like they might be farther apart than two unrelated very long words in the very bushy part of the Cayley graph.

Comment: Sorry my explanation was messy:  my idea is that john.loves.mary would be closer to john.loves.jane than to john.kicks.football.  That's the idea.

Comment: $ab$ is the dot above $a$, right?  Compare this with the distance between the pink and green dots.

Comment: I'm not talking about the pink and green dots. I'm talking about two points in two different but nearby bushy parts of the Cayley graph (say the bushy part to the left of the vertex above $a$ and the bushy part below the vertex to the right of $b$). They don't share a common prefix but they're closer than $a$ and $ab$ are, which do.

Comment: Ohhhhhh you're right... I guess my whole idea has to be re-formulated... but you've helped me a lot :)

Comment: PS:  I think the word metric satisfies my condition, it's just broken in the Cayley graph embedding in $R^2$.  Thus it seems that my condition implies hyperbolicity.  The question remains, whether matrix representations exist that satisfy my condition...

Comment: Holy... you compared D(a,ab) with D(abbbb...,baaaa...) but in my condition the comparison is D(x,y) with D(x,z), sharing one common node.

Comment: Update: my condition **is** satisfied by the Cayley graph in $R^2$; in fact it is the essence of how we draw the Cayley graph, by shrinking successive edges by 1/2 so that edges won't clash.

The Cayley graph in $R^1$ (or $R^4$ etc) shows that matrices can exist under Frobenius norm whose distances obey my condition, thus my condition seems weaker than hyperbolicity.

The question remains whether such matrices can be representations (they'd be necessarily faithful).

Comment: Sorry, I was still wrong.  Nodes that belong to the same "bush" are not necessarily closer together than nodes on different bushes.  It seems that the proper setting for this is the hyperbolic disc.  There the distances may have nice properties....

Comment: Errr... my condition is still not true on the hyperbolic disc.

Comment: Ohhh I remember also:  my property should be stated in terms of cones!